# komodo IDE -> remote debug php using komodo+xdebug: how to watch the $_SERVER variable?

Tags: php, xdebug, remote-debugging, komodo, server-variables

I've setup komodo IDE together with xdebug to do remote debugging PHP. Everything is working fine. Now i want to watch some variables while debugging is in progress. I can watch any variables without problem but i couldn't watch any PHP SERVER variable, for example how to watch the $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] , If i use $_SERVER or SERVER or $SERVER , it will return 0. Anyone know how to do it ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Komodo has a specific tab for super globals. In the bottom left it has "Watch", "Locals" and "Superglobals". For SERVER, GET, POST etc, you'd want the "Superglobals" tab to be activated.

Comment: Thanx , the problem is the superglobals is empty, and right-click menu is disabled. Btw thanx for the answer, it really gave me the idea to find the solution. There's a bug with xdebug from komodo so i have to use pecl version of xdebug , now it works. Thanx
Here are the links :
http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2010/01/komodo-ide-xdebug-and-superglobals.html

http://community.activestate.com/forum/superglobals-not-showing-through-komodo

http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=85439